# 100% fluid width 100% height layout in Bootstrap jQuery works fine in FireFox but is totally messed up in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, webkit

### This now working thanks to help from Kristian

https://jsbin.com/qivevo/1/edit?html,css

The final solution is different jQuery.

---

**Original Question:**

Here's a layout I did by cobbling together various things, it works well in FireFox, but in Chrome the outerHeight is not being calculated correctly or it's slow. I have no clue whether or not this is fixable.

View this: jsbin.com/yuyey/1 in FireFox on a tall monitor, if all the content fits the height, there are no horizontal scroll bars, as you shrink the window shorter getting into the content in the primary column, the footer hits it and doesn't overlap and you can scroll to get to it, this is the desired behavior. Look in the same monitor on Chrome, though it works better now with a script I added, it is not calculating correctly and it's covering up the content.

DEMO: jsbin.com/yuyey/1

**FireFox works as intended:**
[image: Firefox]

CODE:

```
/* uses a script to get height, but with or without this script it doesn't work in chrome as it should */
    var navbarht = $('.navbar').actual('outerHeight');
    var footerht = $('.footer').actual('outerHeight');



 function columnHeight() {
     // Column heights should equal the document height minus the header height and footer height
     var newHeight = $(document).height() - (navbarht) - (footerht) + "px";
     $(".primary-col").css("height", newHeight);
     $(".secondary-col").css("height", newHeight);
     $(".tertiary-col").css("height", newHeight);

 }


 $(window).on('load resize', function() {
 $(".primary-col").css("height", "");
     $(".secondary-col").css("height", "");
     $(".tertiary-col").css("height", "");
     columnHeight();
 });


 //$('.site-main').css('padding-top', $('.navbar-fixed-top').outerHeight() + 'px');

 var bumpIt = function() {
         $('.footer').css('margin-top', -(footerht) + 'px');
         $('.sticky-footer-wrap').css('padding-bottom', (footerht) + 'px');
     },
     didResize = false;

 bumpIt();

 $(window).resize(function() {
     didResize = true;
 });
 setInterval(function() {
     if (didResize) {
         didResize = false;
         bumpIt();
     }
 }, 250);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the problem is that the negative margin lets the footer overlap the content because it can go to high up. We need to fix this by adding the same amount of space in the bottom of the main content by adding some padding:

http://jsbin.com/rakadizo/1

```
 var bumpIt = function() {
   $('.site-main').css('padding-bottom', (footerht) + 'px');
   $('.footer').css('margin-top', -(footerht) + 'px');
 },
 didResize = false;
```

Comment: You're right, the calculation was wrong since it's a static navbar, but even calculated right: http://jsbin.com/vatih/2, it's still not working. The footer is either static or relative so that it doesn't cover up the content when the view port is shorter. In firefox it just works.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is then. It seems to be working fine here. Have you tried my link? Maybe you can try and clarify it a bit?

Comment: View this: http://jsbin.com/yuyey/1 in FireFox on a tall monitor, if all the content fits the height, there are no horizontal scroll bars, as you shrink the window shorter getting into the content in the primary column, the footer hits it and doesn't overlap and you can scroll to get to it, this is the desired behavior. Look in the same monitor on Chrome, though it works better now with a script I added, it is not calculating correctly and it's covering up the content.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer I have updated my answer and it now works the same way in chrome.

Comment: You ROCK! I am so grateful. I will test this out in IOS and other browsers, here's to hoping.